# Setting an absolute include_path in PHP

Tags: php, include

I have a number of classes (Managers and Data) that have `include_once`'s. Seems that when I include a data class into a manager, they work fine together...but when I include the manager class in my view to get the data, it's broken. I assume due to the view actually adding the manage to itself which makes the path to the data incorrect since the view is up 3 directories from root `/adoptions/apps/add/` and the manager and data classes are 4 directories from the root. Is that correct?

Since I am new to PHP I noticed that / takes me further back than just the web root. I am running apache on a windows machine and the path to the htdoc is actually

```
c:/Program Files(x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/mywebsite
```

(if that helps at all). I would like to just have all my includes be something like

```
 include_once('/com/mywebsite/data/people/People.class.php';
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you share some error messages so your question becomes more clear. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `include_path` property in the `php.ini` file of your installation. Clear the existing entries if you wish, or add a semi-colon and then `c:/Program Files(x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs`

Then all paths will be relative to that, so you can just go `include("/mywebsite/data/people/People.class.php");`

Alternatively you can do this in .htaccess file:

```
php_value include_path ".;c:/Program Files(x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs"
```

or one of these two methods in your php itself:

```
ini_set("include_path",".;c:/Program Files(x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs");
```

Or `set_include_path(".;c:/Program Files(x86)/Zend/Apache2/htdocs");`